# variable from sql table and loop container

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, business-intelligence

variable from sql table and loop container
I am trying to update active directory details into our companies staff_list table. Created ssis package to bring the data. I have done for one user (top 1) now struggling in loop. Have first name and last name to update other columns but can’t do in loop, if anyone pls help.

- Have execute task which brings all firstname and lastname from
  staff_list table.
- Then have script task to get staff loginID, designation, managername,phone etc.
- Then have execute task which will update then details of user in table.

now I would like to update for all users with loop container if someone please help me with this. Thanks

Comment: post the code. without technical information it is not possible to help you.

Comment: Dump the active directory details into an object variable and then foreach loop container on this variable. Declare some variable which would hold the columns under this object variable and use them to populate/update the SQL table.